Using Rigify, my finger controls are missing
I am rigging a model with rigiffy and for some reason when I generate the rig, my finger controls don't show up.
I have the fingers set up with their groups and bone colections but they just don't exist for some reason




Hi. You wrote "I have the fingers set up with their groups and bone colections". What does this mean? Have you created/added the bones from scratch -or- did you use a sample or meta-rig like the Human Meta-Rig? The Rigify Type might be missing. Have you checked it? It should be limbs.super_palm for the first palm bone (=the upper one of the pointer finger) and limbs.super_finger for each finger chain (first of the 3-bones chain inside the hand).

@Blunder Thanks, that actually worked
